# which scripture does this shloka appear ūbāḥ bhagavān kṛṣṇaḥ śrīdāman parājitāḥ?

Tags: scripture, puranas, bhagavata-purana, reference-request, shloka

Hi I am trying to identify on which scripture does this shloka appear ?

> ūbāḥ bhagavān kṛṣṇaḥ śrīdāman parājitāḥ

ऊबाः भगवान कृष्णः श्रीदामान्  पराजिता:

I roughly translates to **once Sridama became impatient krishna on purpose lost in some sport**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This verse appears in **Srimad Bhagavatam**, in the Dashama Skandha (10th Canto), Chapter 18 - Verse 24.

In this chapter, which involves the defeat of Pralamba by Lord Balarama, the cowherd boys play a sort of running race in which Lord Krsna's team lost and Lord Balarama's team won.

Hence, the winners were carried by the losers, and so Krsna carried Shridama, who was among the winners.

[Srimad Bhagavatam 10.18.24](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/18/24/):

> उवाह कृष्णो भगवान् श्रीदामानं पराजित: ।
> वृषभं भद्रसेनस्तु प्रलम्बो रोहिणीसुतम् ॥ २४ ॥
>
> **uvāha kṛṣṇo bhagavān
> śrīdāmānaṁ parājitaḥ** |
> vṛṣabhaṁ bhadrasenas tu
> pralambo rohiṇī-sutam ||
>
> Defeated, the Supreme Lord Kṛṣṇa carried Śrīdāmā. Bhadrasena carried Vṛṣabha, and Pralamba carried Balarāma, the son of Rohiṇī.

During the course of the above game, Balarama killed the asura Pralamba and gained victory.